# jQuery - paddingTop animating issues?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

So, I'm building a site for a client and I'm trying to nudge the hyperlinks down when they're hovered over. paddingLeft works with this method and it moves the link over when I use it BUT when I change the value to 'paddingTop' or 'marginTop', I don't get a response. What am I missing here?

http://jsfiddle.net/Raylin/XLrBH/

For those who can just tell what the problem is, here's my jQ code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sublink").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingTop: "+=40px"},200);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingTop: "0px"},200);
    });
});
```

I just learned HTML/CSS/jQuery the other day so, I'm sure it's something simple. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `display:block;` to your link class, that worked on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".circle").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingTop: "+=40px"},200);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingTop: "0px"},200);
    });
});
```

take the outer element as 'the' element for animation.

-- while looking at this animation, I think you should take a look at the  "+=40px". does it really do what you need?

Comment: I took out the '+=' and it works better - in essence.
The code you described moves the circle as well.
I'd like to just move the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sublink").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({top: "+=40px"},200);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({top: "0px"},200);
    });
});
```

This assumes that you add following CSS property to your `.subLink` class:

```
position: relative
```

I didn't test it, but it should work without excuses.

Hope it helps.